# store data dynamically in database

Tags: laravel

I want to save article input dynamically in database This is my code now and I want to save paragraph_two , paragraph_list , paragraph_three in dynamic way how should i change my code?

ArticleController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $index_imageName = $request->file('index_image')->store('uploads');
        $header_videoName = $request->file('header_image')->store('uploads');
        $text_imageName = $request->file('text_image')->store('uploads');

        $new_file_data=[
            'small_explain'=>$request->input('small_explain'),
            'title'=>$request->input('title'),
            'paragraph_one'=>$request->input('paragraph_one'),
            'paragraph_two'=>$request->input('paragraph_two'),
            'paragraph_list'=>$request->input('paragraph_list'),
            'paragraph_three'=>$request->input('paragraph_three'),
            'important_body'=>$request->input('important_body'),
            'quote'=>$request->input('quote'),
            'author_quote'=>$request->input('author_quote'),
            //image storage
            'index_image' => $index_imageName,
            'header_image' => $header_videoName,
            'text_image' => $text_imageName,
            ];
        Article::create($new_file_data);
    }
```

and this is a part of blade:

```
<div class="form-group row" id="paragraph">
   <label class="col-12 col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right">پاراگراف اول</label>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-6">
             <textarea required="" class="form-control" id="paragraph" name="paragraph_one"></textarea>
         <br>
              <button type="button" class="btn " id="button" onclick="myFunction()" 
                                    style="color: white ; background-color: #242849">افزودن پاراگراف
              </button>
        </div>
</div>
 @section('scripts')
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
           var x = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
           var t = document.createTextNode("اینجا بنویسید");
               x.appendChild(t);

           document.getElementById("paragraph").appendChild(x);
                            }
    </script>
 @endsection
```

migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('index_image');
            $table->string('small_explain');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('paragraph_one');
            $table->string('paragraph_two');
            $table->string('paragraph_list');
            $table->string('paragraph_three');
            $table->string('header_image');
            $table->string('important_body');
            $table->string('text_image');
            $table->string('quote');
            $table->string('author_quote');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I'm new to laravel and I really don't know what changes my code need to make it dynamic
by dynamically mean:I have one paragraph and it name is paragraph_one , user can add paragraph two-three-four.... and save it in database
 I wanna khow how to do it

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "dynamically"?

Comment: But, if you just want to save the data (dont know what you mean about dynamically in this case), you put your fields in a `<form> element` with a method of POST (remember the CSRF token within your form). This POST request you catch in your routes file, which then points to your controller that saves in the DB.

Comment: I have one paragraph and it name is paragraph_one , user can add paragraph two-three-four.... and save it in database I wanna khow how to do it

Comment: Can the user only add up to paragraph three, which is stated in your migration? If not, and they can have all the paragraphs they need, this is not the architecture you need. Ill try and show you in an answer

Comment: Your current database design is too rigid; anytime you have `column_X` (where X is a number), consider using a proper relational structure, i.e. a separate `paragraphs` table, linked back to the parent table via a local/foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, So I think I get what you mean.

Your users can add X paragraphs to a form. Then you want to save these paragraphs, but you dont know how many each user created. Can be 1, and 100.

So there are multiple ways of constructing such an architechture. Without stepping on anybody's toes, I need to point out that this is how I would do it. But again, many ways of designing it.

1. option (IMO best option):

2 tables:
1. is your article.
2. is your paragraphs, where you link back to your article ID in an `article_id` column. Then you can find all the paragraphs based on article ID.

2. option:

Making them into an `array()`, and then storing this in your article table, eg. that you save them as an `array();` and push the paragraphs to that `array,` and save this array in `paragraphs_array` column in your article table.

---

In your JS, you want to call them paragraph_1, paragraph_2 etc, and not paragraph_one, paragraph_two. For each time a person creates a new paragraph, you update a `<input type="hidden" name="count_para" value="">` with the number of that parapgrah, example 5.

Then in your controller you do a `for(x=0, x<$request->count-para, x++){}`

Comment: Personal opinion, but I'm not a fan of arrays in databases. JSON arrays are ok (but still not great), as long as the DB supports JSON columns and searching, but too often people use CSV string arrays (`'[1, 2, 3]')` and wind up with more issues with searching/indexing/etc.

Comment: I definetly agree, was just a way to give OP different options to choose from. But i dont enjoy it either, and will create a ton of problems/dev hours down the road.

Comment: I think option 1 is better I should creat another table and this should have text and paragraph_id columns with foreign key connect this table to article table, that's right? and what happen to my controller?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another table. Let's say

```
article_paragraphs
```

With the following fields (just an example, you can modify as you wish):
`id, text, article_id (fk)` etc.

I hope you got the idea. :)

Comment: I think I got it but what about my controller how to send data to database?

Comment: You have to change your code accordingly. You will send an array of paragraphs from the client-side (in your form you can send an array of input, google it if you already don't know) along with other article fields and then you will create a record of an article and then you will create entries in article_paragraphs table using the array of paragraphs.